# How do you link 2 apps within django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-apps

Basically I have built the basics of a website.

I am now wanting to implement a blog on the website as another app.

How do I go about linking the URLs, views, models within these apps?

Also, with the templating do I have to insert the blog webpage to the blog app or keep it on the main website app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create new app as , `python manage.py startapp newapp` command, and in the settings.py module, add `newapp` as installed app

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, I just need yo clear somethings up that I am confused about. 

1. The second part of my post.
2. Should I remove the views from the main app for the blog and place them into the blog app views or keep them and rewrite them to add more into the blog app?

Comment: click the following link, https://github.com/CoreyMSchafer/code_snippets/tree/master/Django_Blog/11-Pagination/django_project............... this project is Django blog app and you can see how files are structured

Comment: You can learn more https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UmljXZIypDc&list=PL-osiE80TeTtoQCKZ03TU5fNfx2UY6U4p, this is an excellent tutorial